# matplotlib: create and save a full-screen figure in a function call

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, fullscreen, figure

How can one create and save a full-screen figure in a function call using matplotlib?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def SolutionCandidate():
    # creating some figure
    x = list(range(1, 8))
    y = [xx*xx for xx in x]
    fig = plt.figure('SolutionCandidate')
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.plot(x,y)
    #
    # making the figure full-screen
    mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
    mng.resize(*mng.window.maxsize())
    #   
    # saving the figure
    #plt.show(block=False)
    plt.savefig('temp.png')

SolutionCandidate()
```

How to make sure that after the function call `SolutionCandidate()` a full-screen figure is saved?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In order for the notion "fullscreen" to carry any meaning, you would need to show the figure on a full screen first. Then you can save it. `plt.show();
    fig.savefig('temp.png')`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : I have tried it already: see the `plt.show(block=False)` call in the `SolutionCandidate` source. The saved figure is not full-screen.

Comment: In my proposal, there is no `block=False`, because in that case subsequent code is executed before the figure is actually shown, meaning you would not save the resized figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : This definitely does not work. If I do not put `block=False`, I have to manually close the figure before it is saved, which defeats the whole purpose. Function `SolutionCandidate` has to produce a full-screen figure file with no other action from the user except calling the function.

Comment: Can you go into detail about the pupose of "fullscreen" here? Why does it need to be "fullscreen" and not just a defined size?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : It can be a defined size, I guess. I can adjust the size to be close to full-screen on my monitor. The purpose of doing it: 1) to make it usable for automated figure drawing and saving (no additional user input has to be required), 2) to make the figure look more or less nice (full-screen figures do look good, and, unfortunately, the default size looks like dog breakfast - this is true, at least, for the specific types of figures I need to draw).

Comment: Ok, then I would recommend just passing a defined size, like e.g. `plt.figure('SolutionCandidate', figsize=(19.2, 10.8), dpi=100)` in case you have a 1080p monitor, or whatever suits your needs.